# How do I center text over an image in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to center my text over an image, however, it will not center. I have looked at various questions here on Stack Overflow, but none will work.

```css
footer {
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.jumbotron {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Wave_Panorama.jpg/1024px-Wave_Panorama.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 500px;
  text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
}

.jumbotron h2 { 
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute; 
  text-align: center;   
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<footer>
  <section class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <h2>By Me</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

I am quite new to HTML so if my code is messy/ confusing/ just plain wrong, that may be the reason. I was also trying to fix it with code snippets from Stack Overflow, so if some parts are unnecessary, please tell me so I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you know, just clean up the code a bit...
*removed the superflous `<div>`container, put `flex: 1 1 0;` where it should be, and removed some other non-sensical CSS as well.

```css
.jumbotron {
display: flex;
text-align: center;
background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Wave_Panorama.jpg/1024px-Wave_Panorama.jpg');
background-size: cover;
color: #ffffff;
height: 500px;
text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
}
.text-center {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.jumbotron h2 { 
font-size: 60px;
font-weight: 700;
text-align: center;   
}
```

```html
<footer> 
<section class="jumbotron">
<div class= "row text-center">
<h2>By Me</h2> 
</div>
</section>
</footer>
```

Comment: *"just clean up the code a bit..."* - And that will magically fix it? Or did you make a fundamental change as well?

Comment: You should state what you did to "clean it up" and why the previous didn't work. Your solution is good because it's making use of flex-box feature without adding extra `position` declaration.

Comment: LOOK at the code - it's about 25 lines of code, it should be fairly obvious. But fine, I'll edit the description a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Make position `relative` instead of `absolute`

```css
footer {
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.jumbotron {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Wave_Panorama.jpg/1024px-Wave_Panorama.jpg');
background-size: cover;
color: #ffffff;
height: 500px;
text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
  
}

.jumbotron h2 { 
font-size: 60px;
font-weight: 700;
margin: 0;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
position: relative; /* MODIFICATION */
text-align: center;   
margin: 0;
 
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<footer> 
<section class="jumbotron">
<div class= "container">
<div class= "row text-center">
<h2> By Me</h2> 
</div> 
</div>
</section>
</footer>
```